# Force Mac to display in grayscale

Tags: macos, color

Is there a way to force OSX to display in monochrome(also known as grayscale)?

I'm working with a student who has ADHD (and I am mildly ADHD myself).  The colors are too much for him/her to handle.

**EDIT:** Ideally I'm looking to assign a keyboard shortcut or create a desktop icon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved with AppleScript and Automator.

The setting to automate is located in:

**System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Use Greyscale**

The keyboard combination <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> also shows Accessibility options.

This Apple discussion, [Keyboard shortcut for "Use grayscale"](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24936825), shows how to use AppleScript and Automator to create a menu bar item that toggles the Greyscale on/off.

Comment: Might there be a way to define such to a shortcut?  Maybe keyboard or dock icon?

Comment: @LiamWilliam In the Accessibility Pane, you can check "Show Accessibility status in the Menu Bar" for easy access to the pane. Also, the keyboard combination OPTION+COMMAND+F5 brings up accessibility controls.

Comment: The linked script no longer works for macOS Sierra. Might someone post an updated one?

Answer (score 2):

As of Sierra you can **tell Siri to ‘use grayscale’**, the closest thing to a shortcut I’ve been able to discover so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can grayscale the display from the accessibility settings, but it's a real pain if you want to temporarily enable/disable it. I have made an app to solve this problem. It allows you to toggle grayscale mode from the status bar.

Tested to work on macOS Mojave.

You can download it [from here](https://shubhamjain.co/quick-grayscale/). The source code is [here](https://github.com/shubhamjain/quick-grayscale).

**Note**: Due to Apple's restrictions you need to allow it to have accessibility and system events permissions.

Comment: Hey, could you make it work on Sierra ?

Comment: After replacing the AppleScript in [`quick-gray.py`](https://github.com/shubhamjain/quick-grayscale/blob/master/quick-gray.py) with the one from [here](https://www.macscripter.net/t/toggling-color-filters-inconsistent-behavior/73402/2) it worked for me on macOS Catalina. As a bonus the script has the advantage that it doesn't open the System Preferences window while it toggles the grayscale mode. Made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Based on a few StackExchange posts (mostly the credit goes to [RecursivelyIronic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/310325/recursivelyironic)), I have packaged a solution with instructions into a GitHub repository: [macOS-grayscale](https://github.com/strogonoff/macOS-grayscale).

It requires compiling a binary, which can then be assigned a hotkey combination (instructions in the repo).

On plus side it:

- toggles fairly quickly
- doesn’t cause a popup
- doesn’t interfere with color inversion
- works on Catalina

Comment: Hey, could you make it work on Sierra ?

Comment: I don’t use Sierra anymore.